# Huge SQLite DB on Android app doubles its size

Tags: android, sqlite

I decided to put more than 400 photos stored as encoded jpg as blob in a SQLite db inside an app (to prevent the user to directly access to the pictures).

The db came out quite large (around 54Mb)
when i install my app on the device, in settings/applications its total size is 99.83Mb
(44,83Mb application, 55,14Mb data)
Before adding the pictures, the app was 9,26Mb

How is it possible?

Comment: Are these images changing?  If not, why not just put them into resources in the app?  They will be inside the apk and the user won't have direct access to them.

Comment: That's the size of the entire app, right?  Not just the SQLite database.

Comment: images are not changing, i just tought that compressing them in jpg and encoding them into a db would have saved space...

Comment: How are the images being stored in the database? Is it possible that they're being cached somewhere?

Comment: i don't think so... they are just big strings in the sqlite file, i don't know how is possible that this affects also the app size

Comment: Following Aleks advice, i put all the pictures in resources and the total app size dropped to 47,43Mb... i guess i'm going with this solution, still i don't get what causes the double size problem